# BluetoothServerSocket doesn't return from accept()

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, serversocket

I'm trying to build a little Bluetooth-Android-App for a project in school.

I'm quite new to Android (got my phone since 2 days). I'm experimenting since 2 weeks with android programming on my laptop. Installed a VirtualBox with Android x86 (eeepc) so I can use the `BluetoothAdapter` of the laptop. Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and is quite slow. That's about the project...

The problem/question:
A Bluetoothconnection has 2 devices - a connecting and a listening one. The listening device has a `BluetoothServerSocket`, that loops `accept()` method until `accept()` returns a `BluetoothSocket`.
In my case the `accept()` method doesn't return so I get stuck and the app freezes with blackscreen asking mit to stop the app or just to wait. When I pass a timeout to `accept()` --> `accept(10000)` I get an `IOException` after the timeout.

listening device:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

    private BluetoothSocket tSocket;
    private BluetoothServerSocket bss = null;

    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "erzeuge ServerSocket");
            bss = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("BluetoothChatInsecure", MainActivity.BT_UUID);
            Log.d(TAG, "ServerSocket OK");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Fehler Serversocket");
        }

        while (true)  {

            Log.d(TAG, "Versuche zu akzeptieren");
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Akzeptieren Anfang");
                tSocket = bss.accept(10000);
                //this line is never reached
                Log.d(TAG, "Akzeptieren Ende");

                if (tSocket != null){
                    //Hier wollen wir hin!
                    Log.d(TAG, "Verbindung akzeptiert");
                    ConnectedThread conThread = new ConnectedThread(tSocket);
                    conThread.run();
                    bss.close();
                    break;
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Fehler, keine Verbindung");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException währent accept-loop");
                //this exception is triggered every 10 sec, when the accept(10000) times out
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Acceptthread hat fertig");          
    }

}
```

connecting device:

```
try {
    socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MainActivity.BT_UUID);

    outstr = socket.getOutputStream();
    instr = socket.getInputStream();

    ois = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstr);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've read a lot of threads on stackoverflow and some other forums about this topic, but I didn't got a solution for the problem.
Sorry about my English, but I am not a native speaker.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I forgot to write, that I test the app with 2 devices. My laptop does accept-loop, while I use my phone and try to connect.

Comment: The `accept()` call should happen in a seperate thread, not on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!
accept() is allready in a thread i think?! When the activity call onCreate() i create an AcceptThread.

Comment: How are you starting the thread? Do you know that you have to call `.start()`, not `.run()`? If it really was on a seperate thread, I don't think that your activity could become irresponsive.

Comment: read the javadoc documentation of the Thread class

Comment: **Thank you** the GUI doesn't get stuck now, but still no success on accept().

Answer (score 1):

This is just the normal behavior: `accept()` will "wait" (block) until a connection has been made from another device. Then it returns the socket representing that connection for further data transfer.

As you have seen, the timeout is signalled via an `IOException`. The contract of `accept()` is that it never returns `null` but always a valid socket, or fails with an exception thrown.

Therefore, thejh is right in saying that you should have a dedicated thread which waits for connections in `accept()`.
When `accept()` returns a new socket, you may want to spawn another thread to handle further communication over that socket, while the `accept()` thread loops to wait for the next connection.

N.b.: You cannot shut down a thread blocked in IO (as in `accept()`) via `Thread.interrupt()`, but you have to close the `ServerSocket` from another thread to cause an `IOException` to 'wake up' the blocked thread.

Comment: I allready spawn a new thread to handle the connection, wenn accept() return, but it doesn't. I forgot to say, that i tested the app with 2 devices. The laptop does the accept-loop, while i use my phone to do the connceting part.

Comment: Then I guess the phone fails to connect to the laptop too?

Comment: Does your phone 'know' which device to connect to? Do you specify the laptop's BT address anywhere in your Android code?

Comment: Yes, the app searches for other bt-devices, then i choose the laptop --> on laptop i press to receive connections --> on phone i press "connect"

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing this problem for a couple of days. 
Finally, I realized why:
I was creating the Thread that accepts incoming connections in the server twice. Thus, the ServerSocket was being created to times, although only the second time the accept() method was called.
This leads to server not accepting any connection!!

Comment: this seems not to be an answer. Consider editing your answer to highlight the things that helped you to overcome issues from the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't call `socket.connect()` from client side in the shown codes.

Answer (score 0):

Today I continued work on project. I got IOException after failing connect() from connecting device.
Now I managed the devices to have a socket, after pairing them before running the app.

EDIT: accept() returns a socket now, but it isn't connected when asking with isConnected().
Socket of the connecting device is connected.

Comment: It should be connected however. Have you tried to transfer some data in either direction via the [input](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getInputStream%28%29) or [output](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) streams?

Comment: i can't get the streams. In the try-block where i wan't to get the streams of the socket triggers IOException.